# Writing an image to linux framebuffer distorts the image C++

Tags: c++, image, ffmpeg, framebuffer

Im trying to set up `rtsp` video stream from **teledyne Dalsa Genie Nano** camera. For grab images I'm using a framework provided by this company.
For `rtsp` stream I will use [ffmpeg tool that can stream video directly from linux frame buffer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#fbdev-1).
So i tried to write this image via memcpy function and at this moment the image is not recorded correctly. because when i try to take a screenshot from *Facebook* with ffmpeg in output i have corrupted image.
Here's some information:
[image: image from camera]
In the framework I have an image object that contains:

1. void *address (address of one frame)
2. int width (**1280)**
3. int height (**1024**)
4. int depth  (**1**)

So I wrote a function:
[image: my function]

It's working fine without any errors but when I print image from *frame buffer* (*fb*) I have

[image: this]

I think it happens because *fb* device depth is 32 but frame depth is 1.

Am I right?

I tried to change *fb* device depth with [fbset](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fbset) tool but it returns an error -
[image: console error output]

Command I use for taking an image from fb:  `sudo ffmpeg -f fbdev -framerate 1 -i /dev/fb0 -frames:v 1 screenAA3.jpeg`

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: please add the output of `sudo fbset -i`

Comment: Do you want to convert the image you get from the framework to a jpeg image or do you want do display it on the framebuffer? (if you just want to save the data as a image (e.g. jpeg) using the Magick++ libary (from ImageMagick) would be easier and less complicated)